# Does stripe payment api for web work on mobile browser?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, stripe-payments

I have created a web application using php. I am using stripe api for payments. It works perfectly fine on web and I can see the payment in the stripe dashboard. When I access the website on my mobile browser I could still navigate but when I make the payment (which works till the end giving success) I cannot see the payment in the dashboard. Does this mean that stripe api for web does not work on mobile browser ? Is there any way I can solve it.

Comment: Please read the very fine documents - https://stripe.com/docs/mobile

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I'm using Stripe Checkout at my site (e.g. `example.com`), and when I use iOS (Chrome or Safari), Stripe Checkout creates a new window instead of a popup. Submitting the form seems to pass validation, but then Safari says “Safari cannot open the page because it could not connect to the server.” But using the same Checkout button from desktop browsers works fine. Those docs have not helped.

Comment: I have the same problem. Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: yes, you can use stripe checkout